# Tab Bar disappears in MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, mobile, mfslidemenu

I have a tab bar with 5 tabs and associated views added in storyboard. The first page seen in app is the view associated with first tab. In each of the five tab views , I have a menu button which gives a side menu which I implemented using MFSideMenu Controller. On clicking menu button , a table view appears from the left side. Table view contains a button named "MyProfile". On clicking it another view, say "Home View " appears. The problem is tab bar disappears in Home View. Is it possible to just show the tab bar without any selection in Home View. Thank You

Code:

for the action of menu button to bring the table view from left

```
- (IBAction)menuButton:(id)sender { 
[self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil]; 
}
```

on clicking the "MyProfile"

```
- (IBAction)myProfileTapped:(id)sender { 
[SlideMenuUtility setCenterViewController:@"HomeNavigationVC"]; 
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed]; 
}
```

Comment: Please show code how you implement MFSideMenu and how you push your view when click on button.

Comment: for the action of menu button to bring the table view from left- (IBAction)menuButton:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
}                                                                     on clicking the "MyProfile"  - (IBAction)myProfileTapped:(id)sender {
   [SlideMenuUtility setCenterViewController:@"HomeNavigationVC"];
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
}

Comment: you should add all this code to  your question not in comment.

Comment: when you add tabbarcontroller?

Comment: i have also face same issue my tababr is got hidden... what to do?